# Ajax/ Jquery script to handle wtf forms gives error when clicking link to other page on site

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

I have figured out what is happening here and have been able to 'patch' it such that the error doesn't happen anymore but I am quite certain that this is not the best way to go about it and would appreciate some advice on how to handle this better.

**The problem:**

I have an ajax/ jquery script that handles forms, it works fine for my form in my home.html but when I navigate to another page it creates an error. This is because a form object (that I created using the WTF forms module in flask) is passed to the template 'home.html' and the ajax script expects to be there (which indeed it is in the case of home.html).But it is not there in the page I navigate away to. The ajax expects it to be there because I have included all my script files at the end of the body of 'base.html'. 'home.html' inherits base.html and the page that I navigate also inherits 'base.html' which includes that script file to handle the form.

**The 'patch':**

Pass an instance of the same form object to my new page even though it doesn't use it, but will make the ajax happy that it is there.

**Possible solutions:**

1) move that script from base.html to the end of home.html. But I might need this script for other pages that do have forms

..any others?

Thanks,